# iOS: Background Color -- UITableView and Accessory to have same background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar.  When I select the cell, I'd like the entire cell to have a [UIColor grayColor];

With the code below, the contentView color appears Gray; however, the background accessoryType color shows up as blue:

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if (self.lastSelected && (self.lastSelected.row == indexPath.row))
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [cell setSelected:NO animated:TRUE];
        self.lastSelected = nil;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // Not working
        [cell setSelected:TRUE animated:TRUE];

        UITableViewCell *old = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelected];
        old.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [old setSelected:NO animated:TRUE];
        self.lastSelected = indexPath;
    }
```

How do I make the Blue appear also as [UIColor grayColor]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are changing the background color of the content view which is just a portion of the cell view.

[image: UITableViewCell representation]

Change the background color of the entire cell. However you can't do that in your `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` because it won't work as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> **Note**: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method of the delegate and not in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the data source.

In your case, keep track of the row selected in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` by saving the index in an ivar and reloading the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    _savedIndex = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([_savedIndex isEqual:indexPath]) {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.  Though I found an easier answer: [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray]; that worked for my case, I'm assuming most people would probably agree with your answer.  If you can also include a code to keep track of the selected cell, I'd like to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Right, i was assuming you wanted the cell to be painted with a custom color but as you pointed out for gray color `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];` works as well :-)

Comment: Although the question was for selecting a cell, I have had that accessory view problem many times! To get around it I've subclassed and drawn a similar chevron. This explanation, plus the amazing diagram, have helped me out BIG time. +1 for sure. Thank you @andreagiavatto!